# What is the expected sendmail behavior if RefuseLA and QueueLA have the same value?

Tags: sendmail

I came across a sendmail server with `QueueLA` and `RefuseLA` set to the *same* value (50).  I'm not sure why the previous admin would have done this.  Is there a legitimate reason for why someone would want to set that? How would sendmail behave in that scenario?

Based off of historical logs, it almost looks to me like it flops between the two enforcement behaviors.  I see some stuff where messages instantly get queued (`stat=queued`) and others where the incoming connection is rejected... but no clear indication of why one action was chosen over the other.

Comment: Are you talking about `sendmail.cf`, `submi,cf` or both?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip `sendmail.cf`(although the param was defined in `sendmail.mc`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `QueueLA` and `RefuseLA` to the same value makes some sense if you want to reduce number of sendmail states. It configures just two states "normal" and "full overload" with no states between.

`RefuseLA` rejects **new** incoming SMTP connections/sessions but sendmail may receive further messages over already existing connections - `QueueLA` will handle them. It is handy in default `background` delivery mode. Think about fast SMTP session sending multiple messages to many slow SMTP destinations and sendmail forking delivery process after receiving each message. [It is possible to limit number of messages accepted in single SMTP session.]

I would not use such configuration myself but IMHO it is mostly matter of personal preferences (preferred "style").  I sometimes use "Keep It Simple Stupid" approach myself :-)